# How to apply texture based on normal coordinate?

Tags: texturing, image, normals, normal-map, coordinates

I'm working on a project where I need to place two different texture one on the **blue side** and another on the **pink side** based on the output of **Normal Coordinate** from the **Texture Coordinate** node *([See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfIm3.jpg) below for better understanding)* but I'm not able to figure out how to do that. Is there any way to separate the normals to use in a **Image texture** so it will only apply to normal value not the other one.

[image: Screenshot that shows what it was meant by the first line of the question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture coordinate/normal is just the object space normal.  You can use the dot product with an arbitrary, unit-length vector to sort the samples into two parts: those that are facing the arbitrary vector will have a dot product >0; those that don't, won't.  You can use a math/greater than node to mix between two image textures like so:

[image]

Faces pointing toward object +X (arbitrary vector 1,0,0, the +X vector) will use the second image, while other faces will use the first image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate you for your time for helping me.